# ASP.Net User Control hover causing click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am working on an ASP.NET webforms application.  On my page I have a repeater that includes a LinkButton.  I have a need to trigger a LinkButton's Click() action when a user hovers over the linkbutton.  I can trigger the click using the mouseover event.  In the .cs file I add the onmouseover event like this:

```
previewButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "document.getElementById('" + previewButton.ClientID + "').click();");
```

The problem, of course, is that the click event is triggered immediately, even if the user just brushes the mouse over the linkbutton.  This is rather annoying, so I've been trying to get this to work on a hover event rather than a mouseover event.

Searching led me to the hoverIntent jquery implementation, but I'm having a bear of a time figuring out how to get it to work correctly.  My (admittedly faulty) understanding was that I had to attach the javascript to the LinkButton in the .cs file, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add that correctly to the linkbutton.  I've tried testing with alert boxes like this:

```
previewButton.Attributes.Add("hover", "document.getElementById('" + previewButton.ClientID + "').hoverIntent(function(){alert('mouseover');}function(){alert('mouseout'});");
```

but the alerts never show when I hover over the link.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion you should *not* have the application do stuff like this. If the user wants to click the link/linkbutton, let him/her click it. Personally I find it very annoying when applications do these kind of tricks. I should be able to put my mouse wherever I want without the application guessing that I probably want to click the link... Anyway, just my opinion...

Comment: I agree that we shouldn't automatically click on things for the user.  In this case what I really need to happen is have a hover event cause some server-side processing, so that I can retrieve data and show it in a popup.  So the LinkButton, rather than being a user-clickable feature (although it is that), serves as a hover target more than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after looking through the suggestions and trying them out, I was able to find an elegant solution that does all its work client-side.  Here's what I did:
First, in the .aspx page, I assigned a css class to each of my HyperLink controls:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="PreviewButton" runat="server" Text="preview" OnClick="PreviewButton_Click" CssClass="previewLink"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then I added a javascript function that attached to each item of that class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var btn = $('.previewLink');
        btn.hoverIntent(function (e) {
            e.target.click();
        }, function () { });
    });
</script>
```

After making sure that I had the hoverintent plugin:

```
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.hoverintent.minified.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It works the way I expect it to.  When I hover over the link, my OnClick function gets called and the preview that is supposed to pop up shows just like I want it to.

Now my only problem is that only the first hover works--the rest of them fail.  So I'm off to troubleshoot that.

Thanks!  And thanks to TheBosZ for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the hoverIntent plugin, as it specifies on [it's documentation](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) you should use the `hoverIntent` method. Now the problem is, you're attaching events inline into the html element, that's not supported as you need to attach the event using jQuery.

Try using `RegisterStartupScript`, on you `Page_Load` event:

```
String csname1 = "hover1";
Type cstype = this.GetType();

// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
{
    string script = "<script>$('#" + previewButton.ClientID + "').hoverIntent(function () { $('#" + previewButton.ClientID + "').click(); });</script>";

    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, script);
}
```

This way you will be attaching the event through jQuery. Note the difference between native HTML events (what you were assigning) and jQuery events like `hoverIntent`.

---

**Personal opinion**

I don't like ASP.NET WebForms javascript implementation in the server as it makes bundles from scripts you include. If you try to include both from the server and from the client, as inline code or `script` tags, things start to get nasty and it's really hard to know in which order scripts are added, and you might end up doing bad stuff as loading jQuery twice or something like that.

My recomendation is to choose how to include your javascript, either from the server (which i don't like at all) or just do it on the client and properly divide client-side from server-side, but don't try to mix both.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are registering the event using jQuery:

```
previewButton.Attributes.Add("hover", "$('#" + previewButton.ClientID + "').hoverIntent(function(){alert('mouseover');}function(){alert('mouseout'});");
```

Comment: that won't work, you're assigning te hoverIntent when the hover event fires. You're not taking advantage of hoverIntent at all, and you're also attaching the event multiple times.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I just wanted to emphasize the jQuery usage, your answer is complete.